# Can sublime text be used as hex editor?

Tags: windows-7, windows, window, hex-editor, hexdump

I am trying to open the skype .dat hex files and I would like to know if I can use Sublime text instead of the other 'dedicated' hex editors.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Sublime text is one of my favorite editors. You can extend its capabilities by using plugins.

I use its plugin `HexViewer` to view hex files. http://facelessuser.github.io/HexViewer/

- In Sublime Text, press `ctrl` + `shift` + `p` (Win, Linux) or `cmd` + `shift` + `p` (OSX) to bring up the quick panel and start typing Package Control: Install Package. Select the command and it will show a list of installable plugins.
- Start typing HexViewer; when you see it, select it.
- Restart to be sure everything is loaded properly.

[image: HexViewer]

Comment: Seems really good but frustratingly I can't figure out how to open it after it's installed. The documentation doesn't tell you the keyboard shortcuts, nor are they listed in any key settings file anywhere.

Comment: Lack of documentation for opening plugins seems to be a common theme. I managed to find it by going to Tools > Packages > Hexviewer > Toggle Hex Viewer

Comment: I used this happily but now it says "Can't find package HexViewer" every time I open it and I can't find it in the install menu. **Was it removed?**

Comment: Yes, but how can you _edit_?

Comment: Found: `HexViewer: Export Bin`.

Answer (score 7):

Once the HexViewer is installed in sublime text, press "Ctr + Shift + P" to open the "command palette" now just type "HexViewer: Toggle Hex View", you can now see the hexadecimal code as well.

[image]

All DOC in
http://facelessuser.github.io/HexViewer/#hexviewer-toggle-hex-view

Answer (score 4):

This can be done without installing any plugins. Simply open the file and select `File` -> `Reopen with Encoding` -> `Hexademical`.

HexViewer has a richer UI and additional features, but this works out of the box.